# Google FireBase plus Backend Logic

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im thinking in creating a very simple App using Google-FireBase as MBAaS. The new tools provided seemed very interesting, i do have some doubt though.

Let's say I have a shared todo up list, but i want to limit the task each list may have, so if an user is adding an item beyond that limit i would like that "the server" notifies it cannot be added (and do not add it obviously) or if all todo items are checked i would like t send a push notification.

Ive read some post but they are old and do not have new google fire base service in  mind. Is this possible using the new suit, if not which alternatives there are without hosting my own backend. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Firebase realtime database, it is possible. You'll want to look at [saving data as transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data) (to avoid multiple users adding on the the list and passing the limit) as well as the different listeners available for [retrieving data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data) (to see when to send push notification).

Comment: But doesn't does listeners work on the device? I woud like that the database itself determine when the list is done and push the notifications, and not the App (i might not fully understood what you implied)

Comment: in that case you'll want to look at [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: Ok, ill dig up about the transaction, marking as valid. Thanks